# App for Instagram Videos/Stories download

Tags: apple-store

I am interested in creating a mobile app for downloading videos/photos/stories from Instagram. The idea is simple: the users provide links of the instagram posts they wish to download and they directly save them to their phone's photo library.

Would this somehow violate Instagram's terms of service or Apple's? Would the application be taken down from Apple's app store?

Comment: Have you found any other app in the App Store that allows this?  That's a great way to check if 1) Instagram allows you to save the photos and 2) Apple allows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to get permission from Instagram for it not to be removed, you might also have copyright issues.

5.2.1:

> Don’t use protected third party material such as trademarks, copyrighted works, or patented ideas in your app without permission.

5.2.2:

> Third Party Sites/Services: If your app uses, accesses, monetizes access to, or displays content from a third party service, ensure that you are specifically permitted to do so under the service’s terms of use. Authorization must be provided upon request.